# Mail Signing Certificate – What are the impacts when revocated?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, certificate-revocation, crl

Suppose I open a signed mail on 1st January 2000, signature is OK.
What about this two cases :

1)  If next CRL is to be published one week later, I found it strange that it is “probably” valid until next CRL, this mean that I should wait one week to “trust” the signature ?

2)   I re-opened it on 31st January 2000, the signature is marked as invalid/revocated. How can I know from when exactly it became invalid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if it is set to be revoked the next week when a new CRL is set to be released, I would wait.

Given that you said and put quotations around "probably" in reference to being valid for the remaining week, this would be a red flag to me and again, I would wait the week until next CRL.  If access is not absolutely necessary and required for business operations...I would wait.

To determine when a cert. has been revoked, you can use the command line for windows and a few commands to generate an output file with this information.  Details of how to do so are here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2006/11/30/basic-crl-checking-with-certutil.aspx

This is for Windows systems only.  For linux systems visit:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/verify